# Show UIAlertController from app extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sms, ios-extensions

I'm working on a message filter extension for iOS and I am kind of stuck. I would like to be able to display an UIAlertController whenever a new message is received and it's classified as junk.
The code I have tried so far (in the handle method of the extension):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     let alertController = UIAlertController(title: " TITLE ", message: " MESSAGE ", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
     alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
     let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.init().bounds)
     alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
     alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1;
     alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
     alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

So my question is: is it possible to display an UIAlertController in a message filter extension considering the filter can work even if the app itself is closed? (And if so, what am I missing in the above implementation?)

Comment: No, message filter extensions cannot interact with the user or present any UI.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you, you saved me some headaches!

Answer (score 0):

You need a ***UIWindow*** to present your **UIAlertController**, but you just created a **UIViewController** which is not attached to anything. So you definitely cannot show a **UIAlertController** in extension.